# Есть ли у playmarket (play google) json с данными приложения?

Tags: json, google-play

Вот например как тут [itunes](http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=#&lang=ru), если подставить в адресс id приложения то выдаст json с его данными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Официального нет, есть [неофициальный](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/)